# Why is it that I can't change the value in the array using the array reference if I have given it a value via the pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My program looks like this:

```
char a[10];
char (*pa)[10];
pa = a;
a[0] = 'g';
*pa[1] = 'h';
printf("%c", *pa[0]);
printf("%c\n", *pa[1]);
a[0] = 'r';
a[1] = 'd';
printf("%c", *pa[0]);
printf("%c", *pa[1]);
```

When I run it I get the output:

```
gh
rh
```

How come the line

```
a[1] = 'd'
```

does not change the value to 'd'?

Comment: pa is an array of pointers and pa[0] is pointing to the array 'a' at a[0] but pa[1] is not pointing to a[1].

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and treat each warning as an error. If you do, you have a lot more specific question to ask, like "what does [this warning](http://ideone.com/cKqiVo) mean?" rather than "why does this 1000000 line program crash?" (assuming you somehow come to writing a 1000000 line program).

Comment: `pa = a;` --> `pa = &a;` then Use `(*pa)[index]` or `pa[0][index]`

Comment: @Bluepixy, help! I'm lost in types again... I parse: `pa` is a pointer...to an array of 10...chars. `a[10]` is an array of 10 chars. The compiler, treating arrays as pointers, now should assign the address of `a` to `pa` in `pa=a` but complains and only accepts `pa=&a`. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie arrays decay to pointers to their first element, not pointers to themselves. Hence the types don't match.

Comment: `pa=a` _assignment from incompatible pointer type_ because type of `a` isn't `char (*)[10]`. type of `a` is `char[10]`.

Comment: @Quentin, I understand. Though disassembly shows the same for both `pa=a` and `pa=&a`, there is a conceptual difference.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the address is indeed the same (there's nothing at the beginning of an array, so the first element has the same address as the array), but the types change the behaviour. a `char*`'s second element is one byte away, a `char(*)[10]`'s second element is 10 bytes away (because the element is of type `char[10]`).

Comment: `*pa[1]` and `(*pa)[1]` are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning only value of `a[0]` to `*pa[0]`(there base addresses values)  but not the value of second element.